# PostGIS check if multiline string is included in polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, topology

I want to return all records that the multiline-string is included in the polygon. In the photo below, it should return two records.

Green line (streets) is contained inside two neighbourhoods (white line)

I use `ST_Contains(a."NeighbourhoodWatchGeometry", b.geom);` in the WHERE clause. It doesn't return any record for that street.

```
FROM "NeighbourhoodWatch" a,
    gis_streets b
  WHERE 
st_contains(a."NeighbourhoodWatchGeometry", b.geom);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems "*included*" here means *intersects*, rather than true *containment*; you want to run

```
SELECT nw.*
FROM   "NeighbourhoodWatch" AS nw
JOIN   gis_streets AS gs
  ON   ST_Intersects(nw."NeighbourhoodWatchGeometry", gs.geom)
;
```

Choose the actual `SELECT` list as needed.

Note that you'd do yourself a favor by avoiding anything but lowercase names for objects and relations. It's also an anti-pattern to add the relation name to its columns, like `"NeighbourhoodWatch"."NeighbourhoodWatchGeometry"`.

---

Apart from the [PostGIS docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html), the [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) article about the underlying *DE-9IM* spatial predicate definition has some general info about spatial relation functions, and [this](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html) article by [@dr_jts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/14766/dr-jts) discusses the details of containment.