# How to get polygons contained within another polygon, including those that touch the border in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Tags: postgis, sql, spatial-join

I'm trying to get blockgroups contains within a designated market area polygon in BigQuery. I've tried using `st_contains` and `st_covers` but I still only get the completely contained ones (and not the bordering ones:

```
SELECT a.blockgroup_geom as the_geom,
a.geo_id,
c.total_pop 

FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_blockgroups.us_blockgroups_national` a

join `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.blockgroup_2018_5yr` c
 
on a.geo_id = c.geo_id

join `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.designated_market_area` b
on st_covers(b.dma_geom,a.blockgroup_geom)
where b.dma_name = 'Milwaukee, WI'
```

[image]

What do I need to do to get all of the blockgroups within the dma polygon?

Comment: It does precisely what you ask for, in a literal sense: find all census blocks *fully within* the DMA (either one *contains* the other, or *covers* the other). Spatial relationships are defined by exact rules. You are likely looking for `ST_Intersects`.

Comment: For quick reference, [linking my own answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377145/postgis-check-if-multiline-string-is-included-in-polygon/377148#377148) on a slightly related post: the links there may be useful, there is plenty more info on the general topic on this board.